# Create a function from CMD (Without batch file)

Tags: batch-file, cmd

In batch file, to define a function you put a  `:` sign and then the name of the function

For example:

`:func
copy "test.txt" "D:\test"`

Then when you want to call the function you use goto:

`goto func`

Is there a way to do that without a batch file? To define a function from the cmd?

Comment: You can use doskey macros the have defined commands that you repeat often. http://ss64.com/nt/doskey.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could make a macro.

```js
set "func=copy "test.txt" "D:\test""
```

Then to execute it,

```js
%func%
```

Comment: But `setlocal` and `endlocal` doesn't work at the command prompt

Comment: You're right.  Just tested and `setlocal` doesn't encapsulate a temporary scope, nor does `endlocal` break out of that scope.

Answer (score 2):

Batch (cmd.exe) doesn't knows functions at all.

With labels you can build a construct that works similar to functions and for returning use `exit /b` ( or `goto :eof`),
but in reality this isn't a function.
But labels can only be used inside of batch files!

At the other side you could **use macros**, these are variables with code.
Also no real functions, but can work like one.

Usage of a macro (in this case to get the string length):

```
set "var=abcdef"
%strlen% var
```

And to build the macro you only need to copy this into your command prompt

```
cmd /v:on 

set LF=^


::Above 2 blank lines are required - do not remove
set ^"\n=^^^%LF%%LF%^%LF%%LF%^^"
:::: StrLen pString
set strLen=@for /L %n in (1 1 2) do @if %n==2 (%\n%
        for /F "tokens=1,2 delims=, " %1 in ("!argv!") do @(%\n%
              set "str=A^!%~1^!"%\n%
              set "len=0"%\n%
              for /l %A in (12,-1,0) do @(%\n%
                set /a "len|=1<<%A" ^> nul %\n%
                for %B in (^^!len^^!) do @if "^!str:~%B,1^!"=="" set /a "len&=~1<<%A" ^> nul%\n%
              )%\n%
              for %v in (^^!len^^!) do @if "%~2" neq "" (set "%~2=%v") else echo %v%\n%
        ) %\n%
) ELSE set argv=,
```

But macros have a tendency to become nasty.

Or you could read [DosTips: Executing GOTO/CALL in a cmd.exe](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=6061), it's a little bit advanced technic

Answer (score 0):

`:func` is not a function but label in batch file. I.e. point for `goto`. There is no `return` like in subroutine/function.

Comment: @i486, there is a return if you CALL the LABEL

Comment: @Squashman Ok, it seems new feature. There was no CALL/return in old Windows batch files.

Comment: a return is invoked by either a `goto :eof` or the end of the file